# Not able to upload a file to slack via web-api

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, slack, slack-api

I am trying to upload a file snippet to a channel in slack using Web-API available at https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

```
 payload_channel_caller = {'token': 'xoxpxxxxb1d8529c', 'channel':'C1PJ17FFT', 'file': "/home/nsingh/slack_shift/user_list" ,'title':'Shifters'}

    print "This is a test"
    requests.post('https://slack.com/api/files.upload', data=payload_channel_caller)
```

But the above code is not able to upload the file, infact it runs right through with no error .

Not sure whats wrong here.

Can someone help me out

Comment: I'm almost certain you have to actually send a file object rather than a path to your file so something like `'file': open("/path/to/file", "rb")`

Comment: What's the response? ( `r.content` )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Modification points :

In your script, the file you want to upload is not read. When your script is run, following response is retrieved.

```
{"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}
```

At this time, the status code from Slack is 200. So no error occurs. The script which was reflected above points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
import requests
uploadfile = "/home/nsingh/slack_shift/user_list"  # Please input the filename with path that you want to upload.
with open(uploadfile, 'rb') as f:
    param = {
        'token': 'xoxpxxxxb1d8529c',
        'channels': 'C1PJ17FFT',
        'title': 'Shifters'
    }
    r = requests.post(
        "https://slack.com/api/files.upload",
        params=param,
        files={'file': f}
    )
    print r.text
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: the abovve code still doesn't upload , runs fine though

Comment: I have confirmed that this script works fine. Can I ask you about the error messages and/or response message? And what file do you want to upload?

Comment: oh yeah.. sorry just checked that , it is using my token so i was not able to get notified

Comment: @Kittystone I'm relieved to hear that. Thank you.